# Texture not visible in material preview

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I've assigned material with textures and it displays properly in viewport, however, material preview still doesn't show my texture:

[image: No material preview]

Same thing in Material tab, the texture doesn't show, it's only a white sphere. Am i missing something?
BTW. Why to assign material, we must enter the Edit mode? It's problematic when assigning material to many different objects. Or maybe again i'm missing something here? :)

Blender file:
[image]

Comment: Could you post a .blend file, using a service like [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), or add more screen shot of all your material and texture settings/nodes? There are many things that could be causing this and more details would be very helpful

Comment: I've posted my .blend file (updated the question). I'm just trying to do basic material things, like assign textures with normal maps, specular maps, etc. I'm new to this, so maybe there is a little checkbox that i need to enable, or something like that...

Comment: BTW, you should have packed the texture in with the .blend file...

Comment: Strange, when i open this blend file the texture is already there and displays on the mesh... | Edit: OK, i've downloaded it and this file doesn't have texture, which is strange, because the exact copy of it (in my folder) has textures in its file. I don't know what's going on here, i'll try fix it asap

Comment: OK, i've selected checkbox "pack the image" next to the texture, now it should be inside the file. I've updated my question with new blend file.

Comment: Should I delete the old one?

Comment: Yes please, i don't need it.

Comment: The texture is showing up as completely black, it is the Specular that adds the white. Very unusual.

Comment: Make sure you select the desired UV Map you want to use (Uvset1) under  Mapping. It is working perfectly for me

Comment: Yes, it's set to 'uvset1' but nothing changed. But as you can see, on the mesh itself, the texture is displaying properly. Only material preview window can't render it.

Comment: Tab into edit view and select all in the UV Image Editor

Comment: I did that, and nothing changed, material preview sphere is still white/black. What's this for? - Maybe it's something with my graphical settings in Blender? If i understood correctly, in your case the material preview is working and displays the texture on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The texture is setup correctly, but you have mirror enabled with *reflectivity* set to 1. This means that the material is *entirely* reflecting the environment around it, but as the mirror color is black, no light is actually reflected.

If you disable *mirror*, the texture is visible:

[image]

Note that I also set the specular intensity to 0, otherwise the texture is a little difficult to see (but visible).